# *How to solve "At least 34MB more space needed on the /boot filesystem."?

Tags: fedora, linux-kernel

Running `sudo dnf upgrade` in Fedora 30 is presented with `At least 34MB more space needed on the /boot filesystem.` Error.

I've tired running `package-cleanup --oldkernels --count=2` but it doesn't work.

**Tests**

- Running `du -sm /boot | sort -n` Outputs: `237 /boot`
- Currently these are available in /boot

  ```
  config-5.2.15-200.fc30.x86_64
  config-5.2.16-200.fc30.x86_64
  efi
  elf-memtest86+-5.01
  extlinux
  grub2
  initramfs-0-rescue-8181747493434839ba11074fb41e0b42.img
  initramfs-5.0.9-301.fc30.x86_64-nouveau.img
  initramfs-5.2.15-200.fc30.x86_64.img
  initramfs-5.2.15-200.fc30.x86_64-nouveau.img
  initramfs-5.2.16-200.fc30.x86_64.img
  loader
  lost+found
  memtest86+-5.01
  System.map-5.2.15-200.fc30.x86_64
  System.map-5.2.16-200.fc30.x86_64
  vmlinuz-0-rescue-8181747493434839ba11074fb41e0b42
  vmlinuz-5.2.15-200.fc30.x86_64
  vmlinuz-5.2.16-200.fc30.x86_64
  ```

Comment: Check /boot to see if any old images or initrd files are being left behind. If so, remove those.

Comment: `du -sm /boot | sort -n` output?

Comment: Something is using 237MB on your boot partition, which seems excessive for a few kernels and their initrds.  You need to do some investigation of disk usage. 
 How big are the kernels and initrds etc in /boot (`ls -lh /boot`)?  How big is your /boot partition and what fs  (`df -Th /boot`)?   How much is being used in /boot itself and in sub-directories (`find /boot -type d -exec du -ch {} +` - optional pipe that into `sort -h` to sort by dir size).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The initramfs file `initramfs-5.0.9-301.fc30.x86_64-nouveau.img` is clearly no longer needed, since you no longer have the corresponding kernel file.

Since you only need 34 MB more space, this might be enough.

If that does not free enough space, and your current GPU driver is OK, you might also consider removing `initramfs-5.2.15-200.fc30.x86_64-nouveau.img`, as it appears to be a backup, probably from before installing a proprietary NVidia GPU driver.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `dnf clean all`?

Also you could try to find largest files using `find /boot -xdev -size +100M -exec ls -Alh {}\;`